# Convert CSV style

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I have a CSV file that is formatted in a way that I am unfamiliar with.
The file contains hourly mean power output over a whole year for a couple of generators and the water level in the reservoir of a hydropower plant.

These are the first 17 lines (4 hours) of the file.

```
CTime,textbox1,Name,textbox2
01-01-2021 00:00,Middel,TURBINEG2 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 00:00,Middel,TURBINUG3 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 00:00,Middel,RSVRLEVEL VST,-4.98
01-01-2021 00:00,Middel,TURBINEG1 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 01:00,Middel,TURBINEG2 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 01:00,Middel,TURBINUG3 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 01:00,Middel,RSVRLEVEL VST,-4.98
01-01-2021 01:00,Middel,TURBINEG1 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 02:00,Middel,TURBINEG2 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 02:00,Middel,TURBINUG3 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 02:00,Middel,RSVRLEVEL VST,-4.97
01-01-2021 02:00,Middel,TURBINEG1 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 03:00,Middel,TURBINEG2 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 03:00,Middel,TURBINUG3 EFF,0.00
01-01-2021 03:00,Middel,RSVRLEVEL VST,-4.96
01-01-2021 03:00,Middel,TURBINEG1 EFF,0.00
```

What I want is five columns (CTime, TURBINEG1, TURBINEG2, TURBINEG3, WATERLEVEL) with one row for each hour instead of this (four rows per hour).

I haven't gotten anywhere by simply iterating over each hour of the year and write to columns of a new text file. Unfortunately I haven't come up with any code that is worth bringing up here.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please attach a text file, not a screenshot :-)

This code should do what you need:

```
import csv

with open('csv_in.csv', newline='') as csv_in, \
     open('csv_out', 'w', newline='') as csv_out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in)
    fieldnames_out = ['CTime', 'TURBINEG1', 'TURBINEG2', 'TURBINEG3', 'WATERLEVEL']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames=fieldnames_out)
    writer.writeheader()
    row_out = dict.fromkeys(fieldnames_out)
    while True:
        try:
            row_in = reader.__next__()
            row_out['CTime'] = row_in['CTime']
            row_out['TURBINEG2'] = row_in['textbox2']
            row_in = reader.__next__()
            row_out['TURBINEG3'] = row_in['textbox2']
            row_in = reader.__next__()
            row_out['WATERLEVEL'] = row_in['textbox2']
            row_in = reader.__next__()
            row_out['TURBINEG1'] = row_in['textbox2']

        except StopIteration as e:
            break

        print(row_out)
        writer.writerow(row_out)
```

Comment: Hi, can you precise which language you are using. Thanks